# Identifying the nature of the a stochastic Process

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes

I am new to the Stochastic process. I am interested in identifying the description of a stochastic process. For example,

**Example 1**: let us consider the queue at post office. Let's imagine that we observe the queue every minute. Therefore, at the n-esimo minutes there would be a number of people. We indicate the **Xn** the stochastic variable that indicates **the number of people at the minute n**. Thus, we will have X1, X2, x3,...

**Description 1**: it is a process with discrete time and discrete state. 
**Why?** It is a *discrete time*  because we are interested in measuring the queue every minutes. It is *discrete state* because the possible values for the aleatory variable  Xn are numerable.

**Example 2**: let us consider the queue at post office. Let's imagine that we observe the queue every minute. Therefore, at the n-esimo minutes there would be a number of people. We indicate the **Xn** the stochastic variable that indicates **the average high of people that are in the queue  at the minute n**. Thus, we will have X1, X2, x3,...

**Description 2**: It is a process with discrete time and continue state. 
**Why?** It is a *discrete time*  because we are interested in measuring the queue every minutes. It is *continue state* because the possible values for the aleatory variable  Xn is all R (Real Number).

Is the above correct? if not what is wrong?

Comment: What does it mean when you say "the _average_ number of people in the queue at time $n$"? Is time measured with a 12-hour or 24 hour clock and so you have _multiple_ observations (taken over many days) of the number of people in the queue at time $n$, and can compute their average? If not, with a single observation, how are you computing the _average_ number pf people at time $n$?

Comment: Thanks Dilip, but itis not clear to your question. In which example did I say so? In the Example 2 I mean the "average hight of people..."